# How to secure a dev environment

Tags: nitrousio

I'm using PHP + LAMP container, and a Symfony2 app. I got my dev environment working but right now it has public access (anyone with the link). How can I secure the access to it? I was thinking maybe a ssh tunnel and allow access to the directory only through localhost, but I was wondering if there's a more simple way?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by secure? Nitrous already provides you with a SSH link if you provide a public key, do you need help setting that up?

Comment: @GamesBrainiac, I edited my question, it wasn't clear, sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Nitrous desktop application to forward ports to your local computer, this is just like using a SSH tunnel but we are providing a useable GUI around it.

https://community.nitrous.io/docs/desktop-app-installation